# Is there a way I can use currval() without selecting it more than once?

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to use the current value of an auto ID by giving it some kind of name and just referring to it (instead of calling SELECT for each record):

Requests table has a serial column named `requestid`.

```
insert into testschema.requests (chid) values
(1);
```

I want to use `select currval()` multiple times without having to use SELECT for each line:

```
insert into testschema.requestinfo (requestid, reportid, amount) values
((select currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq')), 10, 40),
((select currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq')), 15, 29),
((select currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq')), 40, 4);
```

I've tried placing the select on its own line with no success:

```
SELECT currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq') as reqid;
INSERT INTO testschema.requestinfo(requestid, reportid) VALUES
 (reqid, 2);
```

**Bottom line**: I want to refer to the currval without having to use `SELECT currval()` for each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not need a subquery in your statement. The bare function does the job:

```
INSERT INTO testschema.requestinfo (requestid, reportid, amount)
VALUES (currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq'), 10, 40)
     , (currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq'), 15, 29)
     , (currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq'), 40, 4);
```

But [`currval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) only makes sense if you have (implicitly or explicitly) called [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) for the same sequence before in your session. In this case, and if you have not called `nextval()` for any other sequences in the meantime, you can simplify with [`lastval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

```
INSERT INTO testschema.requestinfo (requestid, reportid, amount)
VALUES (lastval(), 10, 40)
     , (lastval(), 15, 29)
     , (lastval(), 40, 4);
```

Either way, if you have many rows like this, look to [@dezso's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71167/3684) for a way to avoid *typing* the function repeatedly.

`currval()` and `lastval()` are *volatile* functions:

```
SELECT proname, provolatile
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  proname IN ('currval', 'lastval');
```

| proname | provolatile |
| --- | --- |
| currval | v |
| lastval | v |

Meaning they will still be *evaluated* for every row that way.
To also avoid repeated execution of the function, move it to a separate CTE or subquery and `CROSS JOIN` to your input values:

```
INSERT INTO testschema.requestinfo (requestid, reportid, amount)
SELECT id, v.*
FROM   lastval() id
CROSS  JOIN (VALUES (10,40), (15,29), (40,4)) v;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yxd7iEwi)

Comment: Thanks, I keep forgetting about `lastval()`...

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter . I can not  replicate your last code. here is my demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/v5vpvO_t

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @jian! I fixed the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WITH vals (reportid, amount) AS (
    VALUES (10, 40),
           (15, 29),
           (40, 4)
)
INSERT INTO testschema.requestinfo (requestid, reportid, amount) 
SELECT currval('testschema.requests_requestid_seq'), reportid, amount
FROM vals;
```

This is a nice generic solution for similar tasks.  It neatly separates the fixed values from the dynamically obtained ones.

With big data sets I would swap the `VALUES` 'table' with a real temporary table, though.